# Weird MYSQL backtick (Grave accent)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database, info and comment and their structures are as follow:

```
info (id(int(10)), name(varchar(80)), ...19 other columns.., phone(int(16)));
comment (id(int(10)), name(varchar(80)), comment(varchar(80)), phone(int(16)));
```

When I execute these SQL queries:

```
INSERT INTO info (name, ...19 other columns.., phone) VALUES ('asa', ....., 123456)
```

It works perfectly fine.

But when it comes to `INSERT INTO comment (name, address, phone) VALUES ('asa', 'asa', 123456)`, it reports SQL syntax error unless I surrounded phone the backtick like this `` `phone` ``

Honestly, I can get all the things done by adding the backtick, but I would like to why it works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: thats just a common mysql convention.

Comment: Well, "phone" isn't a reserved word in mysql. Do you have something odd happening with case-sensitivity in your column names in the `comment` table?

Comment: What is the exact error message and SQL error code?

Comment: ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'phone) VALUES ('asa''

Comment: @lc. I don't think so, I named all my columns in lower case with no space/hyphen etc

Comment: I have a suspicion that it might be in your *19 other columns*. Can you post the exact error you're receiving?

Comment: Side note: phone numbers are not numbers. You don't do math with them and leading zeroes count.

Comment: @njk  The query with 21 column works fine, that's why I just simply omitted them

Comment: @user1659006 Can we see the exact syntax error you are receiving?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario and neither are zip codes! Hate finding that when inhereting a legacy app. o.O

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine there is a comma or something in the address that you are trying to insert and it is therefore trying to insert everything beyond that comma into the phone field.

Answer (score 0):

Table structure  `name,`**`comment`**`, phone`

Your sql command `name,`**`address`**`, phone`  (address and comment are different)

Check that all columns and "insert into" names match between them at all.

The error message is important. Please post it if possible.  It is also important to show the whole table column names and the whole "insert into" statement.